# Gradle failing on build, but Maven works

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

So, I have always used Maven.... thought I would try Gradle.

I went through the instruction to just convert my existing maven setup to gradle, this supposedly sets up the gradle environment from the existing Maven environment.

After conversion, I was able to get simple projects to build with "gradle build".

However, more complicated ones are failing.  The problem seems to be the absence of ".jar" files.  Maven seems happy with only needing the ".pom" file for dependencies.. yet Gradle seems to require the ".jar" file.

I am not really sure why Maven does not care about the ".jar".  Maybe it is lazy and assumes it only needs it during runtime, and as long as it finds the ".pom" it can finish the build.  Gradle, then, is not as lazy and requires the actual ".jar".

I don't really know, but am looking for some confirmation on how this works.

Can someone help out?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. For example giving an extract of the dependency graph, the exact error message. Right now the answers will only be about generalities.

Answer (score 0):

Maven also needs all the jar files, except for cases where you only need pom information, like parent poms and boms.

If a dependency does not have a jar file, there is probably something missing in your repository.

Comment: Well, I should have said that the failed dependency is not one that I call out directly in my pom.xml.  It is a third level dependency.  It is listed in the "modules" section of the ".pom" file above it.  I  am not familiar with the "module" section, but will research it.  Does that make it a parent POM?  
"

Comment: The modules section describes the modules of a multi-module project.